# How to hide table data upon load and only show table headers?

Tags: javascript, html, css

On my table page, I want to display only the header rather than the entire table at first.
Upon loading the page, I want to filter the data and display it based on the selected filter. Although the filter portion works, I am unable to figure out how to display only headers `<thead>` upon page load or when Select Location is selected from the dropdown.

Please see the sample code here: http://live.datatables.net/milazige/3/edit

```css
$(document).ready(function () {
  var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    paging: false,
    searching: true,
    lengthChange: false,
    bInfo: false,
    bSort: false,
    order: []
  });

  $('#table-filter').on('change', function () {
    table.search(this.value).draw();
  });
});
```

```html
<head>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://nightly.datatables.net/css/jquery.dataTables.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <script src="https://nightly.datatables.net/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <p>Select:
    <select id="table-filter">
      <option>Location</option>
      <option>Dallax, TX</option>
      <option>Boston, MA</option>
      <option>Sandy, UT</option>
      <option>Washington, DC</option>
      <option>Omaha, NE</option>
    </select>
  </p>

  <table id="example" class="row-border stripe dataTable no-footer dtr-inline" role="grid" style=" width: 100%;">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Location</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Job</th>
        <th>Salary</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>

    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>Dallax, TX</td>
        <td>test1</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>16</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Boston, MA</td>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test2</td>
        <td>test2</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Sandy, UT</td>
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>test3</td>
        <td>test3</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Washington, DC</td>
        <td>test4</td>
        <td>test4</td>
        <td>test4</td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td>Omaha, NE</td>
        <td>test5</td>
        <td>test5</td>
        <td>test5</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hide the `tbody` on load using

```js
window.onload = function () {
  $('#example tbody').hide();
}
```

Whenever the user clicks on the filter options, display it. Modify the code inside `$(document).ready(function () { ... })`

```js
$('#table-filter').on('change', function () {
  $('#example tbody').show();
  table.search(this.value).draw();
});
```

---

#### Hiding `tbody` in `jQuery` way

At the beginning of the script, hide the `tbody` and show it whenever the user clicks on a filter option

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  // hide tbody on load
  $('#example tbody').hide();

    var table = $('#example').DataTable({
    responsive: true,
    paging: false,
    searching: true,
    lengthChange: false,
    bInfo: false,
    bSort: false,
    order: []
  });

  $('#table-filter').on('change', function () {
    // show the tbody when the user clicks on a filter option
    $('#example tbody').show();
    table.search(this.value).draw();
  });
});
```